# TwitterOAuth Store Tokens for offline use

Tags: php, mysql, api, twitter, oauth

Hi sorry for my bad english, i have writed simple app for update status in twitter account.
Twitter Login:

```
    require("twitteroauth.php");
    session_start();
    $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('*******', '***********');
    $request_token = $twitteroauth->getRequestToken('http://127.0.0.1/twitter_oauth.php');
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
    if($twitteroauth->http_code==200)
    {
        $url = $twitteroauth->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token']);
        header('Location: '. $url);
    } 
    else 
    {
        die('error');
    }
```

twitter_oauth.php:

```
require("twitteroauth.php");
session_start();
if(!empty($_GET['oauth_verifier']) && !empty($_SESSION['oauth_token']) && !empty($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']))
{
    require("config.php");
    $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('****', '********', $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
    $access_token = $twitteroauth->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
    $user_info = $twitteroauth->get('account/verify_credentials');
    $username= $user_info->screen_name;
    $followerInit= $user_info->followers_count;
    $oauth_token=$_SESSION['oauth_token'];
    $oauth_token_secret=$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'];
    $update=query("SELECT 1 FROM connect WHERE id_user=(SELECT id FROM user WHERE user='$username' )");
    if(mysql_num_rows($update)>0)
    {
        query("UPDATE connect set oauth_token='$oauth_token',  oauth_token_secret='$oauth_token_secret' WHERE id_user=(SELECT id FROM user WHERE user='$username' ) ");
    }   
    else
    {
        query("INSERT INTO connect(id_user,followerInit,oauth_token,oauth_token_secret) VALUES((SELECT id FROM user WHERE user='$username' ),$followerInit,'$oauth_token','$oauth_token_secret' )  ");
    }
    header('Location: index.php');
} 
else 
{
    header('Location: twitter_login.php');
}
```

I save oauth_token,oauth_token_secret and in index.php, when user have the oauth_token,oauth_token_secret i would like update status:

```
    session_start();
    require("twitterbot/twitterbot/twitteroauth.php");
    require("twitterbot/config.php");
    $query=query("SELECT oauth_token,oauth_token_secret FROM connect WHERE id_user=8");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_row($query);
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: twitter_login.php');
    }
    $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('bSMnfSsk3CTcSV85jKWz1w', 'HeNAG1v2sgxhkq1QyfZDd029JUDdRNGAaO85Nsg', $row[0], $row[1]);
    print_r($twitteroauth);
    print_r($twitteroauth->OAuthRequest('https://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml',
array('status' => "Hey! I'm posting via #OAuth!"), 'POST'));
```

but in index.php i have error, "Could not authenticate you. /statuses/update.xml" and i can't update status...

Answer (score 2):

```
$access_token = $twitteroauth->getAccessToken();
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
$user_info = $twitteroauth->get('account/verify_credentials');
$username= $user_info->screen_name;
$followerInit= $user_info->followers_count;
$oauth_token=$_SESSION['oauth_token'];
$oauth_token_secret=$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'];
```

In this code you are getting an access `oauth_token` but saving the temporary request oauth_token in the database. You need to save the access_token instead.

Comment: And with i use it!?  Acces_token array contain MY information andrea id user manu thabks